# EL session object property

Tags: java, jsp, el

```
${sessionScope.pricer.applicableRateCode}
```

---

```
public class ViewPrices implements Cloneable, Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    // fields      
    public List<RateCode> applicableRateCode = null;
}
```

---

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'applicableRateCode' not found on type com.*.*.ViewPrices

`${sessionScope.pricer}` prints value but **applicableRateCode** won't print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setter/Getter are missing in the class . JSTL EL will access property using standard accessors methods

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a getter method to `ViewPrices`. JSP EL requires them.

```
public class ViewPrices implements Cloneable, Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    // fields      
    private List<RateCode> applicableRateCode = null;

    public List<RateCode> getApplicableRateCode() {
       return applicableRateCode ;
    }
}
```